# displaying recent user activity php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently making a user profile page at the moment. I am displaying the last 5 comments the user posted. But I also want to display ratings the user has made as well. I think the query I have made will do the job, but I am unsure how to structure my while loop. As at the moment it is structured for just comments. I am pretty new to php and just getting the hang of it, so maybe explain in a little more depth thanks.

The query:

```
$comments = mysql_query("select * from users, comments,
rating_ip, places WHERE users.user_id=comments.user_id=rating_ip.user_id AND
comments.PlaceID = places.PlaceID AND users.user_id =
'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ID']) . "' ORDER BY comments.date
AND rating_ip.date DESC LIMIT 5")
or die(mysql_error());
```

the problem I having when trying to structure the while loop, is that I can't think of a way for the code to determine if its a comment or rating.
Here is the loop:

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $comments )) 
{
print '<div class="activity-comment-holder">';
print '<div class="two columns" id="commented-img-thumb">';
print '<img src="'. $info['ImageURL'] . '" class="commented-img"/>';
print '</div>';
print'<div class="six columns" id="user-comments">';
Print "<p class='commented-on'> ".$info['username'] . "</a> Commented on ". $info['PlaceName'] .":</p>";
Print "<class='recent-comments'>".$info['comment'] . "<br /> <br /> "; 
print'</div>';
print'</div>';
}
```

Comment: you need to use alias and instead of select * , better do select `users.username, comments.somecol as someunique_name` ...etc

Comment: Don't use implicit (comma-) join syntax. Use proper JOINs instead

Comment: Okay thanks. Do you have any idea of how I can make some sort of if statement to determine whether it's a comment or a rating coming from the database and for it to retrieve the right columns for each one?